# The AudioRecord object does not allow for 25 seconds buffer

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

If I run on smarphone (Android 6.0.1. Marshmallow) the following code:

```
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    44100,//sample rate
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    bufferSize//25*44100*2*1
);

int state = recorder.getState();
```

aiming to record 25 seconds of mono 16bps wav file, the state value shows value 0, which is different from `AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED` (which in turn is 1).

For smaller lengths of recorded sound, e.g. 20 seconds, it works fine...

Comment: There may be hardware reasons the buffer can't be bigger than a certain size (for example, there may be a max size DMA allows on your architecture).  If 20s works, why not use 20s and read it in 2 chunks?